# Can I save 'Outlining in my MS SQL Query

Tags: text-editors, query, ms-sql

When writing a query, I will often use Cross Apply, or multiple sub queries.

To make the query easy to read I realized you can `outline` parts of the query, and then hide them.

Using: `Edit -> Outlining -> Hide Selection`

[image]

Then that selection is collapsible, like below.

[image]

I find this great as I can hide parts of the query that only act as filters etc.

However, if I save & close the query, the outlining is removed once I re-open.

Which kind of makes it pointless, is there a way I can keep this function in when I close ?